# Error in many-to-many relationship using Fluent API in Entity Framework 6 one model is self referencing

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, relationship

`Category` model is self referencing

```
public class Category
{      
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public Category Cat { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BusinessDetail> BDetails { get; set; }        
}
```

and `BusinessDetail` is like

```
public class BusinessDetail
{
   [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Business Name")]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Contact")]
    public string contactDetail { get; set; }

    // public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    // public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int ? LocationID { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Website Address")]
    public string Website_Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Is Verified")]
    public bool Is_verified { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Added By")]
    public string Added_By { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Added Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Added_Date { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Is Featured")]
    public bool Is_Featured { get; set; }

    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string VerifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

When creating a many-to-many relationship using Fluent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BusinessDetail>()
   .HasMany(c => c.Categories).WithMany(i => i.BDetails)
   .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ID")
      .MapRightKey("CategoryID")
      .ToTable("BusinessCategories"));
```

I get this error

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'dbo.BusinessDetails' that match the referencing column list in the
>   foreign key 'FK_dbo.BusinessCategories_dbo.BusinessDetails_ID'.

I need help on this error.

Comment: Which workflow are you using? In "Code First" should work. Double check your database schema...

Comment: I am Using Code First

Comment: So please show us more of your fluent configuration.

Comment: It is considered polite that when other users take time to help you out, you follow up to their efforts by commenting on them.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to work out your exact example, but the code below works without any configuration:

EDIT:
I added in the code from OnModelCreating and changed the property names to those in your exampe, but it all keeps working. You do realize though, that the ParentId property is not seen as the foreign key for a parent `Category`, but that EF will create a `Cat_CategoryId` foreign key for you?
I advise to start from scratch using my code and work step by step towards the existing code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.Entity;



   public class CategoryContext : DbContext
    {

       public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
        //Fill in later.
       }

    }


public class Category
{

    public Category()
    {
        Children = new List<Category>();
        Details = new List<BussinesDetail>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BussinesDetail> Details { get; set; }

    }

public class BussinesDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BussinesName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

static class Module1
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        using (context = new CategoryContext()) {
            var newCat = context.Categories.Add(new Category { Name = "CatOne" });
            context.SaveChanges();
            newCat = context.Categories.Single;
            Console.WriteLine(newCat.Name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```